# Updating web app settings: Failed to update web app settings: The specified container size is not supported

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

When trying to update the settings for an Azure Function I am getting this message:

[image]

"Updating web app settings: Failed to update web app settings: The specified container size is not supported. Use on of these container sizes: 128, 192, ..."

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in the Function App to increase the container size, it can be set using Azure CLI Powershell (either in the Portal or locally):

```
az account clear
az login
az account set --subscription 812a6b8a-xxxx-yyyy-zzzz-397bd3b744ec
az functionapp update --name functionnamehere --resource-group resourcegroupname --set containerSize=1536
```

It also works for App Services.